# How to use timeit for measuring the runtimes of the functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I want to measure the runtime of the selection sort

```
def selection_sort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        least_idx = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
            if arr[j] < arr[least_idx]:
                least_idx = j
        arr[least_idx], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[least_idx]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    import random

    n = 7
    arr = random.sample(range(2**n), 2**n)
    timeit.timeit("selection_sort(arr)", "from __main__ import selection_sort", number=5)
```

but I'm constantly getting NameErrors, `name 'arr' is not defined` in particular. How to do it and make sure that `number=5` won't run the function on an already sorted list and also python caching won't affect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use functools like this

```
    import functools
    t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(selection_sort, arr)) 
    print (t.timeit(5))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be also grateful if you add a few words about what is does

Comment: partial() "freezes" the function's arguments creating a new object which can be called by the Timer.